# Is it correct to say - The Brenners are two sisters?

Tags: expressions

“Lydia Brenner and Cathy Brenner are two sisters.”

Now is it correct to say – The Brenners are two sisters?

“Lydia Brenner, Cathy Brenner and Mitchel Brenner are two sisters and one brother.”

Is it correct to say –

a.  The Brenners are three siblings.

b.  The Brenners are two sisters and a brother.

c.  The Brenners are three siblings: two sisters and a brother.

---

Do they sound native?

Are there any other expressions that sound more native?

Comment: I think Brenners, holistic representation of family rather than a generation.

Comment: Well, I just used this 'Brenner' as a surname taken from an American movie named 'The Birds'.

Comment: Is there any reference to your question in the movie?

Comment: Look, the sentences I mentioned in the post haven't been taken from that movie directly. The name of that movie is 'The Birds', as I mentioned above comment.

Comment: I would say *the Brenner sisters* or *the Brenner siblings*. Is there some reason that you need to provide a specific count?

Comment: The **two** before sisters - in your first two examples - is redundant.

Comment: In the first sentence 'two' is redundant as there is two names there. I agree for this one. And now what about the second one? Suppose that one is an individual sentence. Someone tries to mention that the Brenner family has two sisters.

Answer (score 1):

For the first example I would say:

> The Brenners are sisters

For the second one I would say:

> The Brenners are siblings; two sisters and one brother

While all your examples are correct they are not commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

More native might be

> The Brenners have three children, two girls and a boy.

or

> The Brenners have two girls and a boy.

or, depending on emphasis

> Mitchel Brenner has two sisters.
>   Lydia and Cathy Brenner have a brother, Mitchel.